# Reorder posts in a loop: have the posts by one particular author below the others

Tags: loop, filters

It's quite long to explain, but i'll try to make it short.

I made a plugin that scrapes content from remote websites; then converts each content request to a post (custom post type).
I assign those "automated" posts to a bot user that I created in my Wordpress.

When displaying my posts in a loop; I would like to give a lower priority to the posts that have been created with this bot.

Thus I would like to reorder them by taking apart the posts from the bot and put them below the others.

How would you do that ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: If you're inserting the posts with the bot, why not give those a higher `menu_order` which is `$post->menu_order` or is the Page Attributes box under Pages. Anyway, this will allow you to order your query by `'orderby' => 'menu_order, 'order' => ASC'`.

Comment: That could be interesting, but I was wondering how to do this with filters... ?

Comment: If you're creating your own `WP_Query` to display posts you could just pass those parameters in. Then there's the `pre_get_posts` hook which allows you to modify main queries.